# Validation in contact form

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

How to add condition in contact form 7 
How to write condition enter email id or phone number in wordpress contact form 7

```js
function custom_validation_filter($result, $tag) {  
      $type = $tag['type'];  
      $email = $tag['email-603'];  
      $phone = $tag['tel-254'];  
      if($email == '' || $phone == '') { 
           
                $result['valid'] = false;  
                $result['reason'][$email] = 'Please enter email or phone number';  
             
      };  
       return $result;  
 };  
 add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text','custom_validation_filter', 10, 2);
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641945/custom-validation-is-not-working-in-contact-form-7-in-ver-4-1-1

Comment: Above code right or wrong because above code not working right now

Comment: would you please refer above link. in place of `$result['reason'][$name]' you have to use `$result->invalidate( $tag, "Your custom validation message goes here." );` and some other minor mistakes.

Comment: I have use $result->invalidate( $tag, "Please enter email or phone number." ); code but not working

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425854/contact-form-7-telephone-number-verification/35600916#35600916.[link] I think this one is help for you.